# How to compare stock time-series with different holidays

Tags: time-series, optimal-scaling

Many researches just assume 252 trading days, means 21 days per month, which is helpful.

But when you need to compare stock returns from different countries, it happens that each stock is not traded (and thus have data of zero) on different days.

That means that even if you delete all "international" holidays like 1 January, this happens.

Do you know any reference do deal with this problem?

My solution would be to find the "lowest common denominator" and just "delete" all remaining days that are above 252 days (assuming for instance that there are holidays in countries although in practive there are not)

**Edit:** Actually my question can be simplified: What using as returns for stocks that were not trading (return = 0) if other stocks in the sample were actually traded (return not 0). Maybe using linear regression on the missing days? However, this would bias the results if the market behaved completely different. But also using 0 would bias the results as this would assume that the stocks were traded but closed without change...

**My best idea seems to be to use the market return as the "best" proxy...**

Comment: What are you trying to do with the daily data?

Comment: I am using the daily returns in a regression and performing this on a large scale with multiple series. Therefore I always need exactly 252 daily returns.

Comment: Yes, this sound a reasonable approach... just thought they could be a "simpler", commonly used method to deal with these missing values. I have some headaches to apply such algorithms in the pre-processing of the data...

Comment: I have seen now 3 different methods: taking the return of the day before the missing data (not good), taking zero (not good), interpolation (i think could be ok), and EM (think this is the best solution). Taking the market return (my first idea) would bias the results ugly... So interpolation or EM seems reasonable